# Does $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+(x\sin5x)^2}$ converge?

Tags: calculus

I would like your help with deciding whether the following integral converges or not:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+(x\sin5x)^2}.$$

I tried to compare it to other functions and to change the variables, but it didn't work for me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: fyi, Mathematica 8.0.4 says it does not converge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it does not converge.  You can argue as follows.  Split the integral up into pieces:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+ (x\sin 5x)^2} \geq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{k\pi/5}^{(k+1/2)\pi/5} \frac{dx}{1 + (x\sin 5x)^2}. $$

For $k\pi/5 \leq x \leq (k+1/2)\pi/5$, note that

$$ \frac{1}{1+(x\sin 5x)^2} \geq  \frac{1}{1+25x^2(x-k\pi/5)^2} \geq \frac{1}{1+ (k+1/2)^2\pi^2(x-k\pi/5)^2}.$$

It follows that

$$\int_{k\pi/5}^{(k+1/2)\pi/5} \frac{dx}{1 + (x\sin 5x)^2} \geq \int_{k\pi/5}^{(k+1/2)\pi/5} \frac{dx}{1+ (k+1/2)^2\pi^2(x-k\pi/5)^2} = \frac{\arctan((k+1/2)\pi^2/10)}{(k+1/2)\pi}.$$

Substituting this into the sum above we find that the sum diverges and hence the integral does too.

Comment: Can you please explain the first inequality in the 4Th row? Thanks!

Comment: Just use the fact that $|\sin 5x| \leq 5|x-k\pi/5|$ for $k\pi/5 \leq x \leq (k+1/2)\pi/5$

Answer (score 6):

Basic idea: Near $x_k = {2\pi k \over 5}$ the integrand is comparable to ${1 \over 1 + 25x_k^2(x - x_k)^2}$. Thus integrates to a term of magnitude $O({1 \over x_k})$. Add up over all $k$ and the integral diverges.

Comment: More rigor please!

Comment: Since this is probably a homework question I didn't want to give away too much.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the intervals $I_k=[(k-\frac{1}{2})\frac{\pi}{5},(k+\frac{1}{2})\frac{\pi}{5}]$. The $I_k$ are the periods of $\sin^2(5x)$.  Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{I_k}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2\sin^2(5x)}
&\ge\left|\int_{I_k}\frac{\cos(5x)\;\mathrm{d}x}{1+(k+\frac{1}{2})^2\pi^2/25\;\sin^2(5x)}\right|\\
&=\frac{1}{(k+\frac{1}{2})\pi}\int_{-1}^1\frac{(k+\frac{1}{2})\pi/5\;\mathrm{d}t}{1+(k+\frac{1}{2})^2\pi^2/25\;t^2}\\
&=\frac{2}{(k+\frac{1}{2})\pi}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(k+\frac{1}{2})\pi}{5}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Since $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(k+\frac{1}{2})\pi}{5}\right)>\frac{\pi}{4}$ for $k>1$, the integral on $I_k$ is greater than $\frac{1}{2k+1}$. Therefore, the integral diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the intervals where

$$|x\sin(5x)|<1,$$ where the function value exceeds $\dfrac12$.

For large $x$, the bounds of the intervals are close to $\dfrac{k\pi}5$ and asymptotically

$$\left|x\left(5\left(x-\frac{k\pi}5\right)\right)\right|<1.$$

Thus after solving the equation, you see that the length of the intervals is asymptotic to

$$a\sqrt{k^2+b}-a\sqrt{k^2-b}\sim \frac {ab}k$$ for some $a$ and $b$, leading to an Harmonic series.

Comment: can you explain the connection between $ |x\sin5x| $ to $ |x(5x-k\pi)| $ ?\

Comment: @FreeZe: $\sin(5x)\sim5x-k\pi$.

Comment: Why is that true?

Comment: @FreeZe: by Taylor. Mh, but I am missing a factor. Fixing...