# Convergence of $\int^\infty_0\frac{1}{1+x^2\sin^2(5x)}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I need to find out whether the following improper integral converges:

$$\int^\infty_0\frac{1}{1+x^2\sin^2(5x)}\,dx$$

I tried two comparison tests that failed, any ideas?

Comment: Thankfully, we already have answers like [*this*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350161/does-int-0-infty-frac11x-sin-x2-dx-converge) or [*this*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564067/does-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-11x-cos-x2-dx-converge). You may also want to look at [*this*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86837/does-int-0-infty-fracdx1x-sin5x2-converge).

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{N\pi/5}\frac{1}{1+x^2\sin^2(5x)}\,dx&=\frac15\int_0^{N\pi}\frac{1}{1+(x/5)^2\sin^2(x)}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac15\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+(x/5)^2\sin^2(x)}\,dx\\\\
&+\frac15\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\int_{(n-1/2)\pi}^{(n+1/2)\pi}\frac{1}{1+(x/5)^2\sin^2(x)}\,dx\\\\
&+\frac15\int_{(N-1/2)\pi}^{N\pi}\frac{1}{1+(x/5)^2\sin^2(x)}\,dx\tag 1
\end{align}$$

The first on the right-hand side of $(1)$ creates no issue and the third integral is easily seen to converge as $N\to \infty$.

We focus attention on the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ and write

$$\begin{align}
\int_{(n-1/2)\pi}^{(n+1/2)\pi}\frac{1}{1+(x/5)^2\sin^2(x)}\,dx&\ge 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+((n+1/2)\pi)/5)^2\sin^2(x)}\,dx\\\\
&\ge 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+((n+1/2)\pi)/5)^2 x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{20}{(2n+1)\pi}\arctan((n+1/2)\pi^2/10)\\\\
&\ge \frac{20}{(2n+1)\pi}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{(n+1/2)\pi^2/5}\right)
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as the harmonic series diverges, the integral of interest diverges likewise.

Comment: ... just hoping to hear your feedback  ... Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark